# Android, AsyncTask, ListView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть фрагмент. Я в `AsynsTask`-е получаю данные с сервера и хочу отобразить в `ListView`. Сам Лист, полученный с сервера имеет 10 элементов, но при это сначала заполняется `ListView` пустой и только при повторном вызове `AsynsTask` заполняется полученными данными.

Как мне заполнить `ListView` до отображения фрагмента?

UPD: код фрагмента:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_get_post, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentPost);
    adapter = new PostListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_news,postsLists, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    new MyTask(getActivity()).execute();

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == 0) {
                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= postsLists.size()-1) {
                    new MyTask(getActivity()).execute();

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Код `AsyncTask`:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{

    Activity activity;
    List<PostsList> list = new ArrayList<>();


    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public MyTask(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String link;
        JSONArray friends = null;
       /* ;*/
        try {
            link  = "http://anika-cs.by/app/liker/get_posts.php?id_vk="+ VKAccessToken.currentToken().userId+"&&offset=0";
            URL url1 = new URL(link);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer1 = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer1.append(line);
            }
            resultJson = buffer1.toString();

            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);

            friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("xxx");


            for (int i =0; i < friends.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

                String id_post = friend.getString("id_post");
                String id_vk = friend.getString("id_vk");

                String s =(id_vk+"_"+id_post);
                arrayList.add(s);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                VKRequest zapros = VKApi.wall().getById(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.POSTS, arrayList.get(i), VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1));
                final int finalI = i;
                int finalI1 = i;

                zapros.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

                        PostListAdapter postListAdapter = null;
                        try {
                            JSONObject responseObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                            Log.d("MyFragment", "responseObject = " + responseObject);
                            JSONArray posts, groups, profiles;
                            if (responseObject.has("groups")) groups = responseObject.getJSONArray("groups");
                            else groups = null;
                            if (responseObject.has("profiles")) profiles = responseObject.getJSONArray("profiles");
                            else profiles = null;
                            if (responseObject.has("items")) posts = responseObject.getJSONArray("items");
                            else posts = null;


                            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (groups == null || profiles == null) postsLists.add(attachClass.postObject(post));
                                else postsLists.add(attachClass.postObject(post,groups,profiles,v.getContext()));

                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VKError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> lists) {

    }

    }
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что при повороте экрана данные отображаются. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите Ваш код.

Comment: @Дмитрий Сделайте Visible.GONE если список пустой. И когда список имеет элементы отобразите его.

Comment: логика проста, после удачного получения данных, дайте адаптеру вашего списка знать, что данные получены, пока данные идут, показывайте что вам нравится, вот выше писали можно видимость убрать к примеру.

Comment: @post_zeew, обновил.

Comment: Заполнить `ListView` до отображения фрагмента не получится. Вы можете загружать данные в асинстаске в активити, а после того, как данные загрузились, передавать их во фрагмент и отображать его. PS. Хранить ссылку на активити в асинстаске – очень плохая практика.

Comment: @post_zeew, А если не сложно, можно конкретнее??Или пример реализации?

Comment: @Дмитрий, Насколько я понимаю, Вам не нужно отображать данные до отображения фрагмента, а нужно чтобы при первом выполнении `AsyncTask` данные отображались. Это так?

Comment: Пройдитесь отладчиком по методу `doInBackground(...)` – тогда поймете, почему в первый раз данные не отображаются. А может в первый раз появляется какое-то исключение? Если да, то покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: @post_zeew, на дебаге все данные нормально отображаются...Исключений нет.

Comment: Рекомендую вместо "голого" `AsyncTask` использовать [`AsynckTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=ru) - данный инструмент специально предназначен для асинхронной загрузки в списки, решает проблемы смены состояний и сам обновляет список при получении\изменении данных.

Comment: @pavlofff, AsyncTaskLoader возможно и помог бы, просто хотел бы разобраться в этой проблеме, сильно уж затронула она меня,хотя с активностью таких проблем никогда небыло.